# In Sencha-touch, how can I make a form popup when a user clicks on an item in a list?

Tags: sencha-touch

In Sencha-touch, how can I make a form popup when a user clicks on an item in a list?

Answer (score 5):

I would attach a listener to the 'itemtap' or 'itemdoubletap' events within your Ext.List instance which triggers the display of your form. That's off the top of my head as I haven't *touched* (rimshot) Sencha Touch since before it came out of beta.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.List

Answer (score 2):

You might want to explore disclosures, which place an arrow on the list item for the user to click, or as Wilhelm says, attach to a regular tap or selection event.

For 'modal' popups, simply create a panel with floating:true. See the docs at http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.Panel and the examples in the User Interface / Overlays section of http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

Answer (score 0):

for this i will guide you please go through link which i have give will help You alot

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/sencha-touch-floating-panel-example.html

Comment: You should summarize the basic ideas/steps involved, so that this answer is self-contained. Link-only answers should be avoided on SO.